How to remove old single-hole kitchen faucet from countertop
Similar to the Jan 13, 2018 post but I do see a stacked hex nut holding the "C-shaped" tray to the underside of the counter.  The problem is the tray (mine is black plastic) has tabs right next to the nuts making it impossible to slip a socket over them.  There isn't enough clearance to get an adjustable wrench over them either.  I am stumped.
Update: I was able to use a needle nose vise-grip vertically over the nut and loosen it.  Problem solved!


When editing a question use the symbol with a zig-zag "mountain" (6th from left) to add an image. It would greatly help you to get a meaningful answer.
